# Develop non-GUI OSGi application with Eclipse PDE

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I would like to leverage Eclipse PDE to develop server-side application without GUI. Is it possible and what is the correct way? Are there tutorials on the web?

I have experience on developing Eclipse RCP applications but how does the process differes when I do not need GUI (swt, etc.), what is the best practice?

Comment: Can you clarify your understanding of "server-side application without GUI"? 

Do you want to develop a program that is invoked from the command line, does some processing and then exits? 
Do you want to develop a program that offers a web service/api or a web site? 
Do you want to use PDE because of your preference for OSGi or just for managing the class path?

Comment: Sorry for delaying the response. My application is currently invoked from command line and I want to use OSGi for structuring the application and simplify its deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically use the same tooling as with GUI based applications.

On the other hand normally you only really need the Eclipse PDE tooling for GUIs.
For non OSGi applications it is easier to just use maven and the maven bundle plugin. In this case you develop the non GUI application like a non OSGi application. Most of the OSGi handling is done by the maven bundle plugin (using bnd). See my [Apache Karaf Tutorials](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials) for some examples.

Another approach is using [bndtools](http://bndtools.org/). It is much more integrated but a little less familiar for maven users.

Comment: Sorry for delaying the response. Thank you for the response and Apache Karaf tutorials. However, I am interested in using Eclipse IDE for development as easy and visual tool. I do can create OSGi application but when starting it it complains that the application must have a GUI. So I wonder if is it possible to use Eclipse for developing applications without a GUI

Comment: You can use eclipse to create non GUI OSGi applications... but it sucks :-) If you do not want to use the maven plugin / m2eclipse style then you should take a look at bndtools. It should cover what you need much better than plain eclipse.